# cron task execute python scripts shown /bin/bash -c prefix (shows on htop monitor)

Tags: python, bash, cron

I'm running many python scripts on cron tasks, every 5 min.

When viewing on HTOP monitor I see that some od the calls starts with "**/bin/bash -c**"

You can see in the image attached:
[image]

What does it means?
Does it mean the task was executed?

Comment: Please do not use images or provide text alternative

Comment: I couldn't copy and paste it from the HTOP, but I have pated the prefix of the command.
Maybe i did't understand what you meant.
What other information should I paste?

Comment: Just try to avoid them, ok?

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/bash -c command_string` means that commands to execute in shell are read from argument `command_string`. You can read it in manual of bash, using `man bash`. So it means the task was executed.

> -c If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string. If there are arguments after the
>   command_string, they are assigned to the positional parameters,
>   starting with $0.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` calls `/bin/sh -c YourCommandHere` to execute your tasks.
So it spawns '/bin/sh`. After that shell executes your command, so it starts`python /path/to/script.py`. This command also spawns`python`, which executes your script.

Just look at `pstree` and you will see something like `cron -> sh -> python -> python`